# Why does Twints "since" & "until" not work?

Tags: python, twitter, twint

I'm trying to get all tweets from 2018-01-01 until now from various firms.
My code works, however I do not get the tweets from the time range. Sometimes I only get the tweets from today and yesterday or from mid April up to now, but not since the beginning of 2018. I've got then the message: [!] No more data! Scraping will stop now.

```
ticker = []
#read in csv file with company ticker in a list
with open('C:\\Users\\veron\\Desktop\\Test.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        ticker.append(row[0])        

#Getting tweets for every ticker in the list    
    for i in ticker:
        searchstring = (f"{i} since:2018-01-01")
        c = twint.Config()
        c.Search = searchstring
        c.Lang = "en"
        c.Panda = True
        c.Custom["tweet"] = ["date", "username", "tweet"]
        c.Store_csv = True
        c.Output = f"{i}.csv"    

        twint.run.Search(c)

        df = pd. read_csv(f"{i}.csv")
        df['company'] = i
        df.to_csv(f"{i}.csv", index=False)
```

Does anyone had the same issues and has some tip?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the configuration parameter `Since` separately. For example:

```
c.Since = "2018-01-01"
```

Similarly for `Until`:

```
c.Until = "2017-12-27"
```

The [official documentation](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/wiki/Configuration) might be helpful.

> `Since` (string) - Filter Tweets sent since date, works only with twint.run.Search (Example: 2017-12-27).

> `Until` (string) - Filter Tweets sent until date, works only with twint.run.Search (Example: 2017-12-27).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried that too, but it doesn't work either. Then I've read this article https://localcoder.org/twint-search-not-working-with-date-parameters-python and included "since" in my searchstring, but yeah does also not work..

Comment: Try replacing `since` with `Since` in your own code.

Comment: I've changed it and get a bit more tweets but still only until April this year. :/